# How to narrow a generic type with TypeScripts is keyword?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class which uses generics. It starts out with a pretty narrow generic, and I want to use a function to widen the type.

Let's say I know that the class generic is a vehicle. Now let's say I want to test if it is a motorcycle. If it is a motorcycle, I want to narrow my types to only the props relevant to a motorcycle.

Is this possible?

Below is an example of the problem I am facing; where when I do, instead of narrowing the type, I am narrowing the type to include both the original generic, as well as the generic I am testing for.

```js
class Foo<T> {
  value!: T;
  is = <B>(): this is Foo<B> => true;
}

const foo = new Foo<{ a: 'b', c: 'd' }>();

foo.value // { a: 'b', c: 'd' }

if (foo.is<{ c: 'd', e: 'f' }>()) {
  foo.value // { a: 'b', c: 'd' } & { c: 'd', e: 'f'}
}
```

As can be seen above, the type ends out as `Foo<{ a: 'b', c: 'd' } & { c: 'd', e: 'f'}>` where what I want is to limit it so it ends out as `Foo<{ c: 'd', e: 'f'}>`

**Edit:** Adjusted to comments from `jcalz`

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: ① What "assert" are you talking about? Could you [edit] to clarify your title? ② You're using the terms "narrowing" and "widening" backwards; omitting properties is a widening (it becomes less specific) while adding properties is a narrowing (it becomes more specific). Could you [edit] to either use the proper terminology or use different words without existing conventions?

Comment: ③ Type predicates are only allowed to narrow;  going from `{a: 'b', c: 'd'}` to `{c: 'd', e: 'f'}` is neither narrowing nor widening, but a lateral move. The compiler is doing the right thing by going from `{a: 'b', c: 'd'}` to `{a: 'b', c: 'd'} & {c: 'd', e: 'f'}`, which is a proper narrowing.  Therefore, the answer to your question as asked is "no, this is not possible". Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer with sources; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Well used the `assert` in place of the `is` keyword, since as far as I understand, the issue would be the same for both keywords - `is` is just really hard to use in searches - updated the title to `is` for correctness.
And sorry for the terminology, it always breaks my head, as making something smaller is widening it :D - again, updated my post

And finally, I think you are right in it can't be done, and I also know the compiler does the correct thing. -

Comment: The specific case I have (simplified):
I have a `class Item<T> { value: T, type: 'some-string' }`. These gets put into a `class Group<K> { items: Item<K>[] }` where `K` is a union of all the different `T`values stored in the group. `type` on `Item` can actually be used to get back to the original `T`, so I want to do something like `item.is('some-type')` to get back to the original type.

Not the best example, it makes more sense in context, I promise - but yeah think you are right, that I am going against what the type system is intended to do - Thanks for the reply

Comment: Also just realized why I was struggeling with this - should have used an intersection instead of a union, and then use type narrow to the specific type using `is` - thanks again for the reply

Comment: The searchable term for the `is` keyword is either "[type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)" or "user-defined type guard function".  So do you want to see an answer here that basically says "this is impossible because type guards can only narrow"? Or is there something else you want to see?